# Is there a way to prevent Emacs from deleting an auto-saved file?

Tags: auto-save

I frequently run shell sessions under Emacs (via `C-x shell`).  My practice is to turn auto-saving on these shell-interaction buffers, so that the resulting (auto-saved) files serve as a persistent record of what I've done (including all the generated output).

This works pretty well most of the time, but occasionally, Emacs deletes the auto-saved file.

The conditions that lead to such deletions are not entirely clear to me, but in any case, I would like to prevent them altogether.

Is there a way to tell Emacs to *never* delete an auto-saved file?

I realize that here I am probably using Emacs' auto-save feature in a way that is very far from the standard use-case for this feature, and therefore, it may be unreasonable to try to do what I am asking about here (i.e. keeping Emacs from deleting an auto-saved file).  If so, is there some other way to have Emacs periodically save a shell-interaction buffer to disk, and ***never** deleting the target file*?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried customizing option `delete-auto-save-files` to `nil`?

> `delete-auto-save-files` is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means delete auto-save file when a buffer is saved or killed.
>
> Note that the auto-save file will not be deleted if the buffer is killed
> when it has unsaved changes.
>
> You can customize this variable.

See also:

- Elisp manual node [Auto-Saving](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html)
- Emacs manual node [Auto-Save Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html)

Comment: Thank you for this idea!  True, I am reluctant to use it, because it would result in the proliferation of *other* auto-saved files that I am not interested in preserving.  BUT, by searching the source code where `delete-auto-save-files` is used, I discovered another, more targeted, way to prevent Emacs from deleting an auto-save'd files.  I've described this alternative in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

At least as far as my installation of Emacs (v. 28.0.50) goes, below is the function responsible for deleting auto-saved files:

```
(defun delete-auto-save-file-if-necessary (&optional force)
  "Delete auto-save file for current buffer if `delete-auto-save-files' is t.
Normally delete only if the file was written by this Emacs since
the last real save, but optional arg FORCE non-nil means delete anyway."
  (and buffer-auto-save-file-name delete-auto-save-files
       (not (string= buffer-file-name buffer-auto-save-file-name))
       (or force (recent-auto-save-p))
       (progn
     (condition-case ()
         (delete-file buffer-auto-save-file-name)
       (file-error nil))
     (set-buffer-auto-saved))))
```

Therefore, it appears that it suffices to make the value of the buffer's `buffer-file-name` variable match that of its `buffer-auto-save-file-name` variable to keep Emacs from deleting the buffer's auto-saved file.

Note that while setting `delete-auto-save-files` to `nil` would cause *all* auto-save'd files to be preserved, making a buffer's `buffer-file-name` and `buffer-auto-save-file-name` variables match disables the deletion of only that buffer's auto-save'd file.